# Blazor DBContext Caching Issue

Tags: blazor

I am playing around with Blazor and pulling data from Postgres Sql, I am having issue with DBContext caching data with the tutorial I am following.

In `Startup.cs` I have added the `DbContext` and a Service I made

```cs
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnection")));
services.AddScoped< UsersService >();
```

Below is my code for the service I created. The constructor takes in the DBContext and it has another method to get users based on an email address

```cs
        public UsersService(ApplicationDbContext pDbContext)
        {
            dbContext = pDbContext;
        }

        public async Task<UsersResponse> GetUserByEmail(string pEmail)
        {
            UsersResponse _response = new UsersResponse();
            try
            {
                List<UsersModel> _usersModel = dbContext.Users.Where(a => a.Email == pEmail).ToList();

                _response.Error = string.Empty;
                _response.Sucessful = true;
                _response.Users = _usersModel;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                _response.Error = ex.Message;
                _response.Sucessful = false;
                _response.Users = new List<UsersModel>();
            }        
            return _response;
        }
    }
```

This works fine and I have a page that accepts an email address then a button that calls this service and retrieves users based on that email address.

My issue is once I call this method then all the users seem to be cached in the DBContext. If I go to the database and change an email address of a user then this change is not flowing back when I call this method again, the DBContext has cached data from the previous call and doesnt go to the database to get the data.

It seems as though adding the DBContext at startup it keeps the cache as long as the application is running. I come from a asp.net background where I would use datasets which doesnt use caching, you just create an instance of the dataset call the method which goes to sql to retrieve the data, then the dataset would get disposed. Am I missing something? Or is there a better way I can query sql data from Blazor similar to datasets where I dont have to worry about caching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be using a DBContext Factory and "Unit of Work" contexts.  See this MS-Docs article - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor.

Using `Async` Db access and a single Db Context is a disaster waiting to happen!